# Gaussian distribution of normals' angular deviation

Tags: distribution, gaussian, deviation

Recently I read NVidia's [Mipmapping-Normal-Maps](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/whitepapers/2006/Mipmapping_Normal_Maps.pdf.)

In the "Estimating Normal Variation" section, it assumes a Gaussian distribution of the angular deviation and give a figure (sorry but I cannot post an image as a new user, please refer to Figure_2 in that paper).

Then my question is, how the Na is represented by a function of Standard Deviation?

Answer (score 0):

The links doesn't work for me but I assume Na is what was represented normal distributed. The function for Na would be:

[image: Na normal distributedf]

with:

- Na as the normal distributed value (x-axis value)
- sigma () as the standard variance
- f(Na) as the probability density (y-axis value)
- mu (µ) as the expected value (usually the average value)